# What should be the Request Format for Adaptive Payments through Paypal REST API?

Tags: paypal

I was able to successfully make simple transaction through Paypal new REST API, but I want to make adaptive payment through it. I googled and read the paypal api documents but could not find how to construct the request format to make adaptive payment. So need guidance for creating the adaptive payment request for REST API.

Answer (score 0):

Adaptive Payment transactions are not yet supported for the REST API process. New features are planned for REST and are added often. There are plans for adding support for Adaptive Payments but there isn't a set date or anything like that.